# asp.net excel plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, nuget

What is the easiest way to save content to excel from .net pages?
I know there are a few packages on NUget but which is the easiest/best to work with?

I only need simple text so I know I can do .csv no problem but I need extra control over formatting such as make the text bold, italic, underlined, change cell colour which I do not believe it is possible to do via CSV.

Comment: excel 2007 + I assume. Openxml sdk allows you to do formatting, but it might be lots of work to get it done. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: as I know, Excel supports html data format, so why dont't you just simply try to use html as output format? Or, please, give more details about your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try EPPlus open source .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

Comment: I have began using this and so far it can do all that I need it to do :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NPOI is good for adding formatting. Open source

http://npoi.codeplex.com/